# Windows 10 Installer Will Not Rewrite or Cover Linux MBR Any More?

Tags: linux, windows, mbr

I'm a Helpdesk engineer who prepares laptop for others.

Today, Jun. 4th 2022, I tried something here:

1st: I installed Ubuntu Server LTS 22.04 in a AMD Laptop with disk partitions manually created for /boot/efi, /boot, /root and /home directories. The rest SSD space is for Windows 10 deployment.

2nd: My Windows 10 image iso is the latest acquired by Windows Media Creation Tool. The version is 21H2 Pro.

3rd: After Windows 10 OS is installed in the partition behind those of Linux, the magic thing happened, Windows 10 system doesn't rewrite or cover the MBR section of my SSD, and Ubuntu is still the default OS, but I can press F12 and select to login Windows partition.

Please refer to the photos uploaded here. So please tell me, does Windows changed from a savage to gentleman?

[F12 Screenshot to Select OS!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQVHI.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you looking to change the default OS? I assume your using Grub?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it's a new UEFI + GPT laptop, and my previous one is BIOS + MBR. I was about to fix Ubuntu boot loader issue after Windows 10 installed as what I did on the old laptop before. But, Ubuntu is still the default OS after rebooting from Windows 10. So I press F12 to check whether the Windows Partition could be recognized, and luckily, I can switch to Windows with the boot partition menu provided by UEFI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from a Master, but it seems that the post is deleted~ However, I copied it as a note to answer myself on behalf of Mr. user6868

*The boot process of modern laptops does not use the MBR at all. You missed a change that has been happening over the past 15 years. Your laptop has UEFI firmware, which by design allows multiple bootloaders to be installed side-by-side (and stores them somewhere else than the MBR – they are now regular files in the "EFI System Partition"; that's the /boot/efi partition that you created for Ubuntu). As far as I can remember, Windows has never removed other bootloaders on UEFI systems; the most it does is move its own boot entry to the top of the list.*

What he or she says is correct, I check the /boot/efi directory in Ubuntu. Both of the boot loaders of Windows and Ubuntu are there. Thanks to bring me back to 2022.

[The screenshot of boot loaders in /boot/efi/EFI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py04b.png)

Comment: Master, if you have a glance on the question again, please leave anything, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).